# How to select the first 10 columns of a headerless csv file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file called test.csv ($testCSV).
There are many columns in this file but I would simply like to select the first 10 columns and put these 10 columns in to another CSV file.
Please note that I DO NOT HAVE ANY COLUMN HEADERS so can not select columns based on a column name.

The below line of code will get the first 10 ROWS of the file:

```
$first10Rows = Get-Content $testCSV | select -First 10
```

However I need all the data for the first 10 COLUMNS and I am struggling to find a solution.

I have also had a look at splitting the file and attempting to return the first column as follows:

```
$split = ( Get-Content $testCSV) -split ','
$FirstColumn = $split[0]
```

I had hoped the $split[0] would return the entire first column but it only returns the very first field in the file.

Any help in solving this problem is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

******UPDATE******

I am using the method as answered below by vonPryz to solve this problem, i.e.:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("a","b","c") -Path $testCSV  | Select a,b
```

However I am now also trying to import the CSV file only where column b is not null by adding this extra bit of code:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("a","b","c") -Path $testCSV  | Select a,b | where b -notmatch $null
```

I need to do this to speed up the script as there are tens of thousands of lines where column b is null and I do not need to import these lines.
However, the above code returns no data, either meaning the code must be wrong or it thinks the field b is not null. An example of 2 lines of the text file is:

1,2,3
x,,z

And I only want the line(s) where the second column is occupied.

I hope I've explained that well and again, any help is appreciated.

*******************ANSWER********************

`Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("a","b","c") -Path $testCSV  | Select a,b | Where-Object { $_.b -ne '' }`

Thanks!

Comment: Re: update.  Import-Csv treats consecutive delimiters as an empty string, not `$null`.  An empty string, `''`, is not equal to `$null` any more than `0` is.  You want to use `Where-Object { b -ne '' }` or `Where-Object { b.Trim() -ne '' }`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got a "CommandNotFoundException" error with this code as it didn't recognise 'b'. However it did directly lead me to the answer......::        `Where-Object { $_.b -ne '' }`

Comment: Oh, duh.  That's what I get for answering questions before coffee!

Comment: I take full credit! :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lack of column headers is no problem. The cmdlet `Import-CSV` can specify headers with `-Header` switch. Assuming test data is saved as C:\temp\headerless.csv and contains

```
val11,val12,val13,val14
val21,val22,val23,val24
val31,val32,val33,val34
```

Importing it as CSV is trivial:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("a","b","c","d") -Path C:\temp\headerless.csv

#Output
a     b     c     d
-     -     -     -
val11 val12 val13 val14
val21 val22 val23 val24
val31 val32 val33 val34
```

Selecting just columns `a` and `b` is not hard either:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("a","b","c","d") -Path C:\temp\headerless.csv | select a,b | ft -auto

#Output    
a     b
-     -
val11 val12
val21 val22
val31 val32
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been testing and it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To start I want to mention that [vonPryz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29796225/3829407) is a superb way of dealing with this. I just wanted to chime in about what you were trying to do and why it was not working.

You had the right idea. You were splitting the data on commas. However you were not doing this on every line. Just the file as a whole which was the source of your woes.

```
Get-Content $testCSV | ForEach-Object{
    $split = $_ -split ","
    $FirstColumn = $split[0]
}
```

That would split each line individually and then you could have populated the `$FirstColumn` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this code and the $FirstColumn variable returns as null for some reason...#

Comment: @Johnathan Not that it really matters but this does work for me but I suppose I would be curious if you get any output from `$split`